# Delete lines before and after a match within a specified tags in SED

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Need to delete before and after of a matching pattern within the tag

```
< mds:insert> 
    < attributeValues>
        < AttrNames
            < Item Value="MyContact_c"/>
        < /AttrNames>
    < /attributeValues>
< /mds:insert>
```

Using

```
sed -i -n '/MyContact_c/{s/.*//;x;d;};x;p;${x;p;}' $file
```

removes only line before and after the matching pattern, need to delete all the contents within the mds:insert tag... Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Can `mds:insert` blocks be nested?

Comment: Did you have gnu grep? with grep -A, -B -C, you can control it easily

Comment: mds:insert blocks are not nested..

Answer (score 0):

It isn't `sed`, but here is one for `ex` using the snippet you posted as the file content for `$file`:

```
kitsune:~$ printf '%s\n' 'set ic
1;/="MyContact_c"/<|?<mds:insert?+;/<\/mds:insert>/-d
%p' | ex -s $file
```

Output:

```
<mds:insert>
</mds:insert>
```

That will print the remains of the file after the first instance of the section is removed. If you want this done for all instances, the command line will look like this:

```
'set ic
g/="MyContact_c"/<|?<mds:insert?+;/<\/mds:insert>/-d
%p'
```

You can use this in the for loop of a shell script if you want this done to multiple files. Naturally you'll want a backup copy if you do such a thing, so make sure to copy the file before altering it if you intend to overwrite it.

By the way, if you've ever used Vim or even vi, these sorts of commands are used for saving, quitting, etc. It is worth adding `ex` to your toolbox of knowledge IMHO.

**Edit**

C Shell users cannot use these commands as-is because they contain quoted newlines, which isn't allowed in a C shell. Instead, you can modify the first command like so:

```
kitsune:~% printf '%s\n%s\n%s\n' 'set ic' '1;/="MyContact_c"/<|?<mds:insert?+;/<\/mds:insert>/-d' '%p' | ex -s $file
```

You can similarly do the same with the other string.

Disclaimer: I'm not a C shell user myself, so there might be a better way, but I don't know it.

Comment: Getting Ambiguous input redirect, when using the above command.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it in sed:

```
sed -e ':a' -e '/ mds:insert/!{p;d;}' -e 'N;/\/mds:insert/{/MyContact_c/!p;d;};ba' filename
```

**EDIT:**

You and I may be using different versions of sed or something. Let's try an experiment:

```
sed -e '/ mds:insert/!{p;d;}' filename
```

It won't do anything very interesting, but I want to know whether it generates an error.

Comment: You might try double quotes instead of single. What shell are you using?

Comment: This also removes the `< mds:insert>` tags.  OP likes to remove the data within `< mds:insert>` tags not the tags.

Comment: @Jotne: The phrasing of the question is unclear, but you're probably right. If the OP confirms it, I'll edit my answer-- it's an easy fix.

Comment: @Jotne & Beta.. Sorry for the confusion need to remove the <mds:insert> tags too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it with `awk`

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} /MyContact_b/ {f=NR} END {for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) if (i+2<f || i-2>f || !f) print a[i]}' file
< mds:insert>
< /mds:insert>
```

It skips two line before and two after `pattern` if its found.